# How to call an arbitrary service for saving changes with breezejs?

Tags: breeze

It sounds like the SaveChanges of BreezeJS is great for quick demos, but most real life applications need some sort of unit of work, business requirements, and/or sanity checks before actually saving to the data store. Is there a way to integrate BreezeJS with an ajax call that deals with inserting, deleting, and or updating the data rather than using SaveChanges?

Answer (score 0):

Breeze allows you to both change the server endpoint for 'SaveChanges' via the SaveOptions.resourceName property. (See the EntityManager.SaveChanges api for more info). You can also intercept the SaveChanges call on the server. ( See Save interception in the Breeze Documentation).

Moreover, there is no requirement that you use the current implementation of the Server side SaveChanges code.  As long as you work with the *SaveBundle* that Breeze sends to the server and return a server side *SaveResult*, Breeze will work just fine.  Admittedly, we don't yet have a great deal of documentation on this process, but the code is open-source and you can certainly see how its done right now.

In a related vein, we are working on an example of using Breeze against a MongoDb running under Node that uses completely different 'SaveBundle' and 'SaveResult' formats.  We should be releasing this within the next few weeks.

Comment: is the SaveBundle a requirement? Can't I make an ajax call and return a SaveResult? I would like to divide the saves into different calls as I don't want to inspect the SaveBundle

Comment: Right now you can, but the process is a bit ugly. However, we are in the process of creating a simpler path via something called a JsonRequestAdapter.  This would let you do what I think you want. We should release an example of how to use this adapter with our MongoDb sample coming out within a few weeks.

Comment: Let me know how I can help in any way. I'm actually developing a real world SPA using BreezeJS and I don't mind being a guinea pig

Comment: Great!  I may just take you up on that.:)

Comment: Jay, is the example using the JsonRequestAdapter published?